# Symfony2 Deep listing categories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello i have one problem with my eCommerce categories. First i will show my database table

```
+----+----------+------------------+--------+
| ID | Parent   |      Name        | Status |
+----+----- ----+------------------+--------+
| 1  |          | Clothing         |   1    |
| 2  |   1      | Women            |   1    |
| 3  |   1      | Man              |   1    |
| 4  |   1      | Boys             |   1    |
| 5  |   1      | Girls            |   1    |
| 6  |   2      | Sub of Women     |   1    |
| 7  |   2      | Wub of Women     |   1    |
+----+----------+------------------+--------+
```

Lets to explain:
Root category is **#ID = 1** and have *NULL* value all sub categories have parent #ID.
Each subcategory has its own root category and identified by ROOT Category ID. I successifully get that data in my menu.

[image]

My repository method is to get all categories where parent is **IS NULL**

```
  public function getAllRootCategories()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT c FROM ISLabECommerceBundle:Category c WHERE c.parent IS NULL ORDER BY c.name ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
```

**Contontroller:**

```
   public function categoryListAction()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine');
        $categories = $em->getRepository('ISLabECommerceBundle:Category')->getAllRootCategories();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
          'ISLabECommerceBundle:Category:list.html.twig', array(
                'categories' => $categories
            )
        );
    }
```

**Twig:**

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
      <li> <a href=""> {{ category.name }} </a>
        {% for sub_category in category.children %}
              <li> <a href="">{{ sub_category.name }}</a></li>
         {% endfor %}
      </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

With this twig i can get only categoris 1 level deep bcs my repository get all categories where parent is null value.

What if I want to have their own category under the category.

**Example**

```
Women   
  -- Sub of women   
   --- Sub of women 2
```

Whit this repository method i only can get ROOT category and 1 level subcategory. What about 3,4,5,6 level? How to do that? Bcs any sub category can have own sub sub sub categories.

Any one can give me example how can i do that. Join/Left Join maybie?

Comment: [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/tentacode/3892186) should help you understand recursive Twig routines.

Comment: I dont understad how can i slove my problem with that! In my case problem is in repository method. Bcs i get only categories with NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can solve your problem by changing your twig template to a *recursive* macro:

```
{% macro recursiveCategory(category) %}
<li>
  <a href="">{{ category.name }}</a>
  {% if category.children|length %}
  <ul>
    {% for child in category.children %}
      {{ _self.recursiveCategory(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</li>
{% endmacro %}

{% if categories %}
<div id="categories">
  <ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
      {{ _self.recursiveCategory(category) }}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

#### I also suggest you change your repository method:

```
public function getCategoriesByParent(Category $parent = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');

    if (is_null($parent)) {
        $qb->andWhere('c.parent IS NULL');
    } else {
        $qb->andWhere('c.parent = :parent')
            ->setParameter('parent', $parent->getId());
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

This gives more control over what you want to select from the database. If you change the repository method you need to change your ControllerAction method call to:

```
$em->getRepository('ISLabECommerceBundle:Category')->getCategoriesByParent();
```

Comment: Hm this work good. Where i can read more about this. BDW Thanks man

Comment: Checkout the [Symfony2 Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html). They have nice explanations for almost everything you need. Also the [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) help a lot when working with templates.

Comment: No i dont need SF2 Doc i need more about making recursiveCategory and examples.

Comment: That is a very special usecase. I don't have any material or links on that. But google might be your friend ;)